# Spring-boot using RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, proxy, resttemplate

I'm trying to use the RestTemplate class from Spring framework to hit an RestFul endpoint. When I debug my program, every time I hit the following statement `final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();` , this following error appears in my console.

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:50055', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:50055', transport: 'socket'
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/FatalBeanException
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.<init>(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:57)
at org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.<init>(AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.java:61)
...
```

Here is my entire code

```
// Set the endpoint
final String url = "https://xxxxxxx/api/yyyyyy";

// Set the Content-Type header
final HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
requestHeaders.setContentType(new MediaType("application","xml"));
final HttpEntity<RequestType> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<RequestType>(request, requestHeaders);

// Create a new RestTemplate instance
final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

// Add the JAXB2 message converters
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter());
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new ResourceHttpMessageConverter());
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new SourceHttpMessageConverter());
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter());


// Make the HTTP POST request, marshaling the request to JSON, and the response to a String
ResponseEntity<ResponseType> responseEntity = restTemplate
        .exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, ResponseType.class);
final ResponseType infoResponse = responseEntity.getBody();
```

Could someone please help me to fix this error ?

Comment: Is this your entire code?

Comment: No, this is the most important part. Sorry for my language.

Comment: your error doesn't seem to relate to the code block you have here

Comment: @Coder, Hi. finally the problem had been fixed. It was a conflict between spring dependencies in my POM. The

Comment: There was a conflicting version of the beans dependency. In addition to these change I cleaned my maven repository and run the maven clean goal.

Comment: glad you could resolve it. It's evident that your issue is not with this code. If possible update you question and post an answer as it might help someone with same issue.